# rxjava, retrofit how to retry(retryWhen) understand specific situation?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I have a function which connect server and login account:

```
Observabe<Response> loginAccount();
```

Most of the time, it can login success:

```
   loginAccount().subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

           System.out.println("success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response authenticationResponseResult) {
          System.out.println(authenticationResponseResult,toString());

        }
    });
```

However, there are serveral times there is an *SocketTimeoutException*.
I only want to retry on *SocketTimeoutException* and **at most retry twice**.

How can I implement?

I know probably I can use retryWhen, but I don't know how to use it only when the exception is *SocketTimeoutException* and how to retry **at most twice**.

Comment: Any Solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 2-parameter overload of `retry`:

```
loginAccount()
.retry((throwable, count) -> count < 2 && (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException))
.subscribe(....);
```